# How to use jupyter notebook with google colab on google drive with sqlite db file?

Tags: python, sqlite, google-colaboratory

I uploaded a sqlite db file named factbook.db.
In the notebook, I started out with:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

my_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Analyzing_CIA_Factbook_Data_Using SQL_1/'

%%capture
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite:///my_path + factbook.db
```

After that, I wanted to see the list of the tables:

```
%%sql
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

But it shows:

```
sqlite:///factbook.db
   sqlite:///my_path
Done.
type    name    tbl_name    rootpage    sql
```

I even tried moving a file from the extra folder and pasted inside My Drive. But that didn't work either.

I ran this query:

```
%%sql
SELECT * 
FROM facts
LIMIT 5;
```

But it shows this:

```
* sqlite:///factbook.db
   sqlite:///my_path
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: facts
[SQL: SELECT * 
FROM facts
LIMIT 5;]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your command here won't work.

```
%sql sqlite:///my_path + factbook.db
```

It will not concat the string. You should test it with current directory first.

```
!cp '/content/drive/My Drive/Analyzing_CIA_Factbook_Data_Using SQL_1/factbook.db' /content
%sql sqlite:////content/factbook.db
```

Check if it works first, then try changing directory.
If it is too hard to escape space, you can create a symlink to make it easier.

```
!ln -s '/content/drive/My Drive/Analyzing_CIA_Factbook_Data_Using SQL_1' /content/sql
```

Comment: Hey Korakot, Thank you. But after trying !ln -s, it shows 'Connected: @factbook.db'. But running a query to show the list of tables, doesn't show anything. Appropriate your time.

Comment: Try `ls /content/sql`. Also `%sql sqlite:///content/sql/factbook.db`. Check every step that could go wrong.

Comment: Here's a working example. I think you need 4 slashes (sqlite:////). https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1k02yRAzAI5W0n4-_AyihaqpEt4TaFZM0

Comment: Thank you for being patient. I don't know what step is wrong I am doing. Still no success. Here is the real whole path:/content/drive/My Drive/DataQuest/Mission_Datasets_and_Codes/Working_with_Data_Sources/SQL_Fundamentals_1/Analyzing_CIA_Factbook_Data_Using SQL_1/  The db file and the notebook are located inside Analyzing_CIA_Factbook_Data_Using SQL_1. As you can see I am learning all these and don't know much. Thank you again.

Comment: I have updated the notebook to load factbook.db directly from github. 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1k02yRAzAI5W0n4-_AyihaqpEt4TaFZM0